# Suggestion to a book with lots of number theory problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

What I am looking for is a book that contains "infinitely many problems", starts from the 
easiest to high level(that can be found in national and even international olympiads).
Are there such books, because so far I had not found even a one like it.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinitely many problems"?

Comment: hundreds of of problems.

Comment: Countable-infinitely or uncountable-infinitely?

Answer (score 2):

I liked ***A course in computational number theory*** by David Bressoud and Stan Wagon, since I like to use *Mathematica*.  You probably don't want the otherwise excellent book ***104 Number Theory Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team***
by Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica and Zuming Feng because the problems are not graduated.

Answer (score 1):

"Problems in Algebraic Number Theory"

[http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Algebraic-Number-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387221824](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387221824)

And you might consider Marcus "Number Fields"

[http://www.amazon.com/Number-Fields-Universitext-Daniel-Marcus/dp/0387902791/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422568022&sr=1-1&keywords=marcus+number+fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902791)

While it is an (excellent) text, in response to your question, at numerous places in the actual verbiage he asks you to show "why"?

For contest stuff: Larsen "Problem Solving through Problems"

[http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Solving-Through-Problems-Problem-Mathematics/dp/0387961712/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422568319&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=larsen+problem+solving+through+problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961712)

It does build and you can pick out the topics specific to number theory - but it might be difficult not to be interested in the other material as well.

Comment: Surely if you're going to mention the second book, you should also mention the analytic number theory problems book that Murty wrote without Esmonde. It is also excellent.